# Live reload JavaScript in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, coffeescript, livereload

I know you can live-edit JS from within the Source panel of Chrome Developer Tools, and I know there are systems for live-reloading of CSS, but can you live-reload JS from the source location (either a URL or local disk, or leveraging Workspaces somehow, or possibly even as a Chrome Developer Tools plugin)?  In particular this would be insanely useful for CoffeeScript-to-JS setups.

Comment: Do you mean something other than reloading the page?  It's not clear how you can reload the global state of one script without reloading the others too.

Comment: @jfriend00: No global state is reloaded, it's hot code swapping. I mean the mechanism already exists and works right there in your Sources panel: edit the script, save, and existing closures use the new code. (Brute force manual approach is to compile your new JS, then copy and paste it in there.)

Comment: An alternative approach to your problem might be to use a livecoding tool like [COLT](http://colt.io), which works with external editors.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's surprisingly difficult to find anyone else trying to do this, considering how powerful it would be.

I've come *close* to achieving automatic live reloading of JS without page refresh; here's what I do:

1. In the inspector's `sources` tab, right click and choose "**Add Folder to Workspace...**"
2. Select to the local folder containing the `.js` you want to sync and click **`[okay]`**.
3. Right click on the `.js` file nested inside your newly-added workspace folder and choose "**Map to Network Resource**", then select the matching `.js` from the page.
4. Make changes to the local `.js` file using an external editor.
5. Click on the `.js` file in the inspector, ensuring it has focus; this will trigger a "Recompilation and update" and your changes should be injected to the page.

Step 5 is the part that needs to be automated, somehow.

If you combine this with a file-watcher that automatically bundles your app into a single `.js` file, you can come close to automatic reload without refreshing the page.

Comment: if you (like me) wanted this to allow live edit of JS, it wont work. You'll get the "worspace mapping mismach error". I found this however: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29351513/chrome-dev-tools-workspace-mapping-mismatch

Comment: I was wondering if either of you guys have gained any progress in this since this post over a year ago. I'm still struggling and even though npm livereload provides this option: **applyJSLive** tells LiveReload to reload JavaScript files in the background instead of reloading the page. The default for this is false. Setting this to true still refreshes the page.

Comment: Small addition. If you load from local file it does work you must runt the local file through a web server e.g python -m http.server in the folder your .html exists otherwise the option match to local file never appears and then you can have the save and reload functionality. 
I mention it because I hadn't found the problem through reading the post

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do that with grunt.js, or gulp.js. Other things like Codekit can do this, as can an add-on for Chrome called LiveReload.

Comment: I already use grunt-livereload. It works without refreshing only for CSS; on JS changes, it reloads the full page for me.