# issue to load data from a .js file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to run a web page with that js file, for some reason, it doesn't want to work and when I try the console it says "Live reload enabled". Does anyone know how I can solve that issue?
.

```
const container = document.querySelector('.datalink')
let listdata = async() => {

    let url = '  http://localhost:3000/indusboards';
    const urlfetch = await fetch(url);
    const urlfound = await urlfetch.json();
    let template = '';
    datafound.array.forEach(element => {

        template += `
             <div class ="element">
             <p><small>${element.serialno}</small></p>
             <p><small>${element.boardtest}</small></p>
             <p><small>${element.testresul}</small></p>
             <p><small>${element.serialno}</small></p>
             <p><small>${element.testdate}</small></p>
             <p><small>${element.testtime}</small></p>
             <p><small>${element.boardlocation}</small></p>
             <a href = "/json_projet/details.html">.... more</a>
             </div>
         
         `
    })

    container.innerHTML = template;
}


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoarded', () => listdata());
```

Comment: you can find your answer below link
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949047/live-reload-javascript-in-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949047/live-reload-javascript-in-chrome)

Comment: Did my answer help you in the end?

Answer (score 1):

You made a spelling mistake change your code to.

`window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => listdata());`

Instead of

`window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoarded', () => listdata());`

or you could use

```
window.onload = () => {
    listdata()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
const container = document.querySelector('.datalink')
let listdata = async() => {

    let url = '  http://localhost:3000/indusboards';
    const urlfetch = await fetch(url);
    const urlfound = await urlfetch.json();
    let template = '';
    datafound.array.forEach(element => {

        template += `
             <div class ="element">
             <p><small>${element.serialno}</small></p>
             <p><small>${element.boardtest}</small></p>
             <p><small>${element.testresul}</small></p>
             <p><small>${element.serialno}</small></p>
             <p><small>${element.testdate}</small></p>
             <p><small>${element.testtime}</small></p>
             <p><small>${element.boardlocation}</small></p>
             <a href = "/json_projet/details.html">.... more</a>
             </div>
         
         `
    })

    container.innerHTML = template;
}


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => listdata());
```